# Value after the while loop with post-increment

Tags: c, while-loop, post-increment

Please explain me why the last printf gives value 11? 
I really don't understand why it happened. 
When a = 10 the condition is not fulfilled so why this value has changed to 11? 
Incrementation goes as soon as the condition is checked?

#### Code:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    while(a++ < 10){
        printf("%d ", a);
    }
    printf("\n%d ", a);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11
```

Comment: Why do you think `a` shouldn't be incremented when `a=10`? Do you understand how post-increment works?

Comment: @BlueMoon I think the answer to your second question is obvious, which in turn answers the first question.

Comment: Now yes, thanks all for your answers, it wasn't obvious for me that even when condition isn't fulfilled this value will be incremented.

Comment: @Misiek777 As such, it's probably going to be generally advised not to write code like `while(a++ < 10)` because it can be confusing/unclear or at least give pause to a developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at `a++ < 10` when `a` is equal to `10`.

The first thing that will happen is `10 < 10` will be evaluated (to false), and then `a` will be incremented to `11`.  Then your `printf` statement outside the `while` loop executes.

When the `++` comes on the right hand side of the variable, it's the last thing evaluated on the line.

Try changing `a++ < 10` to `++a < 10`, rerunning your code, and comparing the results.

Answer (score 3):

The post increment operator increments the value of the variable before it after the execution of the statement.

Let's take an example,

```
int k = 5 ;
printf("%d\n", k++ );
printf("%d", k );
```

will output

```
5
6
```

because in the first `printf()`, the output is shown and only after that, the value is incremented.

So, lets look at your code

```
while(a++ < 10)
```

it checks `a < 10` and then after that, it increments `a`.

Lets move to a few iterations in your loop.

When `a` is `9`, the while loop checks `9 < 10` and then increments `a` to 10, so you will get output for that iteration as 10, and similarly, for the next iteration, it will check `10 < 10` but the while loop does not execute, but the value of `a` is incremented to `11` and thus, in your next `printf()` , you get output as `11`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a simpler piece of code to show what `a++` does.

```
int a = 0;
int b = a++;

printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

I think that you'd expect this to output `1 1`. In reality, it will output `1 0`!

This is because of what `a++` does. It increments the value of `a`, but the value of the expression `a++` is the initial pre-incremented value of `a`.

If we wanted to write that initial code at the top of my answer as multiple statements, it would actually be translated to:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a;
a = a + 1;

printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

The other increment that we have access to is pre-increment. The difference there is that the value of the expression `++a` is the value of `a` after it was incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's post-increment. The compiler will first evaluate `a<10` and THEN increment `a` by `1`.